# tortoisesvn context menu's and windows 7 / Vista UAC

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, tortoisesvn, uac

I'm using Windows 7 and Tortoise SVN.  (although the same applies to Vista)

If, for exampe, I want to download a repo by using the context menu option "SVN Checkout", and want to checkout the files inetpub folder (UAC protected), tortoise SVN cannot due to UAC and gives an "Access Denied" error.

How can I run Tortoise SVN via the context menu "in admin mode" ?

Thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251109/tortoisesvn-and-windows-server-2008-user-account-control):

> right-click on your working copy
>   c:\dev folder, select "properties"
>   from the context menu. In the
>   properties dialog, go to the security
>   tab. You will notice that the Admin
>   user doesn't have full access (the
>   user is not listed there). Add the
>   Admin user and give it full access
>   rights.

Comment: Hi,

Bizarrely, the local admin user (and admins group) does have full rights for the folder. 

It was my "logged on" account that didnt have write permissions to this folder...

Thank you for the help!

Comment: This problem still remains in certain folders such as the Program files folder.

Answer (score 0):

While [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1675362/1879194) does address permission issues, this problem may also be induced by other applications blocking permissions, e.g. if using WinSCP or similar synchronization tools.

In such cases, stop said tools while applying SVN changes.