# TortoiseProc launch failed Error:The requested operation requires elevation

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

I have installed TortoiseSVN-1.6.12.20536-win32-svn-1.6.15 on Windows 7 Proffesional.

TortoiseProc Launch failed :The requested operation requires elevation.

Any option in the context menu gives the same error.

Already troubleshoot- - uninstall and install

- Repair the install
- Checked that all exe's (including TortoiseProc) have the "run as administrator" option checked.
- START>RUN>CMD (enter)>[DOS PROMPT]>C:>"ipconfig /flushdns"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

> Checked that all exe's (including TortoiseProc) have the "run as administrator" option checked.

That's your problem: make sure that option is **not** checked! Only if you allow TortoiseProc to run as a normal user then you won't get the prompt.

Comment: Checked all exe's (including TortoiseProc) have the administrator option checked, still not able to do it.

Comment: NOT checked, NOT checked, NOT checked.

Comment: @NaV: @Stefan would like for you to make sure the "run as administrator" option on the TorToise exe are **not** checked. Since you mention in your comment that option is actually checked, maybe this is the cause of your problem? Try to uncheck that option.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, removing the Run as Administrator flag on the TortoiseProc.exe fixed my problem as well, but i was still having issues with the Repo Browser which i was starting from Visual Studio 2008 via the Visual SVN plugin. I was also seeing the error "unable to open ra_local session to URL".

My VS2008 was also set to run as administrator which seems to apply to any programs started from within VS. Turning this off on Visual Studio fixed my problems attempting to browse and access repositories. Thought it was worth a mention as i have spent a few hours trying to get my new Win7 x64 machine with VS2008 working with Tortoise SVN. I never had any issues with my XP box.

Answer (score 1):

You had the [same error with TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=82), and it turned out to be a `PATH` issue:
TortoiseGit couldn't find `git` (or, actually, some associated `dll`).

Would it be by any chance something similar here?
Since [TortoiseSVN don't need svn to run](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#installsubversion), Is `svn.exe` (or other `dll`s) in the `PATH` (and would conflict somehow with TortoiseSVN)?

---

[This thread](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=2628590) mentions a way to get rid of this message by:

> 1. I successfully did "`SVN update`" with `TortoiseSVN-1.6.7.x` (not 100% sure what version I had, but it was fairly new). I've used `TortoiseSVN` successfully for a few years now. I'm on Windows Vista Business 32-bit SP2 (ENG). Running Windows Security Essentials.
> 2. `TortoiseSVN` saying reported that there is a newer version. I updated (without uninstalling first) to `TortoiseSVN-1.6.9.19​725-win32-svn-1.6.12​.msi`. No other updates to Windows recently (including no Windows updates in the background).
>      Download URL: http://ignum.dl.sour​ceforge.net/project/​tortoisesvn/Applicat​ion/1.6.9/TortoiseSV​N-1.6.9.19725-win32-​svn-1.6.12.msi
> 3. Did *not* restart the computer.
> 4. Tried to use `TortoiseSVN`, e.g. "`SVN log`". Received the error dialog:
>      `TortoiseProc Launch failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more detail.`"
>      All "TortoiseSVN" submenu options gives this including "`TortoiseSVN -> Help`".
> 5. Restarted the computer.
> 6. Still receiving the error.
> 7. Scanned the Windows Registry with CCleaner. There was nothing related to TortoiseSVN, but I cleaned out all issues anyway.
> 8. Still receiving the error.
> 9. Uninstalled TortoiseSVN via the Windows Control Panel. Confirmed that there was nothing left.
> 10. Restarted Windows.
> 11. Removed %ProgramFiles%/TortoiseSVN/, because it contained a BerkeleyDB License.txt.
> 12. Scanned the Windows Registry with CCleaner. Detected:
>       "`Unknown File Extension *.patch", and 3 "Missing MUI References" for TortoiseProc.exe, TortoisePlink.exe and TortoiseMerge.exe`".
>       Cleanup again.
> 13. Reinstalled above `TortoiseSVN`.
> 14. "`TortoiseSVN -> Help`" and "`TortoiseSVN -> Show log`" works now, even before restarting the computer.
> 15. Restarted the computer.
>
> Not sure if Steps 11-12 are needed.

So basically:

- uninstall
- reboot
- clean registry
- re-install

Comment: Could You elaborate more about it plz.

Comment: @NaV: It could be a conflict with a standalone svn installation that you might have (but don't need for TortoiseSVN to run).

Comment: @NaV: just added another process to try to get rid of the message.

Comment: I already double checked it Von; unfortunately there is something else causing this problem. Thanks for the thoughts though.

Answer (score 1):

I right clicked on the tortoise SVN exe and selected to view the properties. In the properties window, in compatibility tab,  "Run as administrator" was checked. I UNCHECKED it and after that i didn't get any error.

I have logged in as an user with Administrator privilege

My problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. The solution for me was:

1. Uninstall Tortoise SVN
2. Open Regedit
3. Modify PATH key in regedit and remove svn
4. Remove all keys from registry containing tortoise
5. Install again tortoise.
6. Voila it works.

I had problems with installation I installed software in tortoise directory instead of tortoiseSVN. I think that caused this problem. I hope it will help someone who had same issue as I had.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to remove SVN from system path? I'm  having the exact same issue and none of the other answers worked.

Comment: depends. If you have it in system/system32 then remove from there. Elsewhere you need edit PATH variable my computer check -> http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0):

Unistall Tortoise SVN and the SVN command tool. Re-install Tortoise SVN with the SVN command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error in which none of the above solutions solved my problem. Even uninstalling, rebooting, cleaning, deleting, rebooting again, and reinstalling did not solve my issue. In the end I figured out that my issue came when I tried to give TortoiseProc admin rights and then I ran it through the context menu. This somehow was "remembered" somewhere in Windows. Even after I unchecked run as administrator and tried to use the shell context menu choices it was still trying to run as administrator. after several days of trying to learn svn cli I finally tried to just run the executable directly which worked. Then the context menu started working again.

I hope this helps others in the similar rut I got into.